# Debian 5.0 dosen`t see java excecutable file

Tags: java, linux, debian

How its possible?

`ls -la|grep java
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  47308 Сен 15 11:41 java
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  47936 Сен 15 11:41 javac
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  47896 Сен 15 11:41 javadoc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  47892 Сен 15 11:41 javah
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  47928 Сен 15 11:41 javap
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   1779 Сен 15 11:33 java-rmi.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  84974 Сен 15 11:44 javaws
qds:/home/qds/bin/jdk1.6.0_22/bin# ./java
-bash: ./java: No such file or directory`

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit Debian and using a 32-bit JDK? This problem can pop up in that scenario because you could be missing 32-bit libraries `java` needs to run. If this is your set up, use `ldd java` to see what it needs (and is missing).

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with birryree's comment:  If you're using a 64-bit OS, either use a 64-bit JDK, or ensure that the necessary 32-bit libraries are available.

(Primarily posting this answer in an attempt to either get this question some additional attention / competitive answers, or at the least, to simply remove this from the growing list of unanswered questions.)